# Opening a PDF with Preview in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have an application, I wish to click a button and open a PDF that would be saved in the application files.

Answer (score 2):

You can say `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:pdf_file];`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
system([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"open %@", path_to_my_file] UTF8String]);
```

This way, if the user likes using another application to open their PDFs, it will open that instead.

Comment: `system()` should generally be avoided if there's any other way to get something done. It's mostly only good for quick and dirty solutions.